# How to write a resume for self educated computer systems experience

Tags: resume, career-development

I have been using Linux, mainly Debian and Gentoo, for years now and am very fluent in Bash as well as how Linux systems are designed as I have spent an obscene amount of time setting up config files manually via vim, for example I am proficient in using fdisk to partition disks in the terminal, /etc/fstab to mount them and make sure I compile using my ram, things like this. In fact almost everything I do anymore is in a terminal. , I am extremely interested now in getting a job as either Linux systems administrator, or entry level software development. I have a basic understanding of Python but I've never written any code really other than to make text games when I was younger in Basic. I also have a technical background from the navy I worked on avionics systems. Since I got discharged tho in 07 my security clearance has no doubt been deactivated and I haven't worked on the books since, as I work under the table for a friend who is a licensed contractor. I am extremely experienced in the hardware and software systems of computer systems I've been using them since the 90's I started on a dos system before windows 3.1 came out. I also am about halfway through a BS in physics. What I am wondering is how to articulate all my problem solving and computer skills into a resume that would land me a decent job.. I may require some training but I know that all this knowledge has to be worth something, I'm not someone who goes around asking other people how to do something I just figure it out as I go. This has to account for something right?

Comment: "make sure I compile using my ram" - what does this mean? When presenting your skills, format it more as a story with paragraphs.

Comment: I hope your CV is not formatted like your question - it is barely readable!

Answer (score 0):

List your experience in terms of projects completed.

In your case I would not be looking for entry level work, I would aim much higher but I would aim for people who already know my worth. Getting a formal job through the normal ways is less likely without any sort of qualifications unless you're in the Third World.